# Autodesk ATF-1008 Error

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am getting an `ATF-1008` error which has no explanation when translating files that previously worked fine. What does the `ATF-1008` error mean?

```
{
            "guid" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLWZ3bGMza2x2ODBvNGN0bXZjMm94c3djZGkuaXB0",
            "success" : "0%",
            "hasThumbnail" : "false",
            "progress" : "complete",
            "urn" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLWZ3bGMza2x2ODBvNGN0bXZjMm94c3djZGkuaXB0",
            "status" : "failed",
            "startedAt" : "Thu May 18 05:29:50 UTC 2017",
            "region" : "US",
            "owner" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLWZ3bGMza2x2ODBvNGN0bXZjMm94c3djZGkuaXB0",
            "type" : "design",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "guid" : "aa85aad6-c480-4a35-9cbf-4cf5994a25ba",
                    "messages" : [
                        {
                            "type" : "error",
                            "code" : "ATF-1008",
                            "message" : [
                                "Error: {0}",
                                "C:\\worker\\viewing-inventor-lmv\\tmp\\job-1\\264\\591ce770371a2102c71d0183-fwlc3klv80o4ctmvc2oxswcdi.ipt"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "hasThumbnail" : "false",
                    "role" : "viewable",
                    "version" : "2.0",
                    "progress" : "complete",
                    "urn" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLWZ3bGMza2x2ODBvNGN0bXZjMm94c3djZGkuaXB0",
                    "status" : "success",
                    "type" : "folder"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Are you consistently getting this error when restarting the translation? You can use the **x-ads-force** header in the [JOB request](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) to make sure it's restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the file had become corrupt after uploading to Forge OSS without supplying a `Content-Length` header. After attempting to convert this file I would get this error. By inspecting the original file contents I was able to see the file had not uploaded as expected.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the ambiguity.